# Disable the status bar in full screen app on swipe up

Tags: android, android-source, statusbar

I'm Working on AOSP 13.

- I have full screen apps installed in my device. When I open it,
  status bar and navigatino bar disabled. But after swipe up from bottom or swipe down from top both are visibled.
- How can i disable status bar in full screen app in way that it can't appear when swipe up from bottom and only navigation bar appears.

Can we do this in AOSP source code ?